# How to keep an object always in front of another object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object and a player. How do I make it so that the object is always in front of the player, no matter what position the player is at?

Hey guys thanks for your replies! Just to add that the object spawns at a random position, then I have made it move towards the player (this is why I haven't made it a child of the player). From then it will always stay in front of the player.

Comment: What did you try until now ?

Comment: So, far I have moved the object towards the player. Which constantly moves towards the player, but doesn't stay in front of it. @SnakeEyes

Comment: and why don't you just add some amount which will place that object in front of your player?

Comment: Hey, what do you mean by `amount`?

Comment: @anaksky2k19 I meant the code you wrote until now

Comment: You could create another Vector3 or just apply on that Vector3 that your working on some small distance that will always point in front of your player. Of course, you will need to check players active side.. in order to always point in front.

Comment: Something like.. myObject.transform = new Vector3(playerTrans.x + 10f, playerTrans.y + 10f, playerTrans.z + 10f); of course you will need to adjust to your needs.

Comment: @anaksky2k19 can you provide us your code that you've done so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set that object to be a child of the player

```
GameObject childPlacehoderObj;   // Set this to the child you want to give a home
GameObject playerObj;  // This will be the parent

childPlacehoderObj.transform.parent = playerObj.transform;
```

Now the child will move along with the parent.

**Update: object spawns at a random position, then I have made it move towards the player**

What you can do then, is to create an empty object which will be the final position of that object. And this empty object you make it a child of the player.

Then what you do is to make the object, one it is spawned, to move to the position of that empty object. You can add something like [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) in the object which should be in front of the player

```
void Update()
{
    // Move our position a step closer to the target.
    float step =  speed * Time.deltaTime; // calculate distance to move
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, childPlacehoderObj.position, step);   
}
```

Finally once the object reaches the target point, you can make it child of the player.

Comment: Yes, this will work, but then the Child needs to be fixed - static.

Comment: Hey, I updated it to elaborate more. The object isn't always static.

Comment: @anaksky2k19 I updated my anseer as well. Give it a try and let me know

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could just set the player as parent of the Object. Like this the Object would define it's Position after the Position of the Player and after it is once infront of the Player it would always stay there no matter his postition.